# AWS CodePipeline double execution for one commit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

When I push new changes to my work branch, two executions are created for that push.

I've tried to reproduce this on other branches, but only happens on some branches of my repository. And I looked for this issue, but this seems to happens to no one.

[image: Duplicated executions]

[image: Pipeline steps 1 and 2]

[image: Pipeline step 3]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain a bit about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @matesio , I've my work branch on my repository and when a change is pushed to remote a new execution is generated on pipeline. My problem is that is generating two executions when a new change is pushed.

Comment: Can you share your whole pipeline structure ?

Comment: @matesio Sure, I updated the question. The pipeline has 3 steps, one for the source, other for the build and the other the deploy for 2 regions.

Comment: So where are two sources for push event?

Comment: Sorry, I'm expressing me bad. When I trigger the pipeline two executions are created, as i show on the 1st screenshot. The source is the same, 2 executions running for the same source. When I go to the steps execution it seems like is running once, but when i go to the history, the pipeline is running twice.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that my pipeline has 2 webhooks associated. I'm generating the pipeline and the Github webhook through AWS CLI, did this happen to someone? Is it possible that when I create the pipeline the creation is automatically generating the webhook and the association?

Comment: To clarify, I went to my repository, and I had found that my repo had two webhooks in it. I deleted one of them and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have source polling enabled and a CloudWatch rule configured?

Comment: No, I don't. I have source polling on false and no rule on CloudWatch.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you configured the integration, Github can create multiple webhooks. In my case two webhooks were created off the same branch. One that triggers on Push and Pull Requests and another that triggers just on push. Hence push would trigger both webhooks. You can edit the webhooks in Github.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply switch my codepipeline source from GitHub Version 1 to GitHub Version 2 and added the inline policy to the appropriate codepipeline role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Action": [
                "codestar-connections:UseConnection",
                "appconfig:StartDeployment",
                "appconfig:GetDeployment",
                "appconfig:StopDeployment",
                "codecommit:GetRepository"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The double execution immediately suspended. Version 1 uses OAuth-based tokens to connect to your GitHub repository. By contrast, the GitHub action (version 2) uses a connection resource to associate AWS resources to your GitHub repository.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, thank you for participating! I am seeing your answer in a review. To increase readability, could you please format the JSON data in your answer? The [makdown-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) should help you get started.